# Android: background computation options

Tags: android, multithreading

I am new to Android application development. My first project is to create a tuner, which requires to record audio and analyse it in real time.

I have read a lot on background operations in Android, but I am having trouble deciding what to use:

- Asynctask : Android documentation says it should be kept for short computations, but I need to analyse data for more than a few seconds.
- Intentservice : Better suited for long computations, but it can't be stopped whenever I want with a button.
- Worker thread : The limitations seem to be similar to that of Asynctask.

On the following link is an example I found that is similar to what I want to do. Can a worker thread still be a good choice for long computations ? Is it thread safe to use a while loop with a flag to stop the computation ?

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Displaying-Sound-Volume-in-Real-Time-While-Recording

Edit: I have successfully created a bound service. Inside this service, a new thread is created to update a value in a loop, which is then broadcast. But when I unbind from the service, the thread continues to run. The value will still be updated even if I close the app and restart it.

So I am back to my initial problem. How is such a thread stopped ?

Edit: Problem solved with a simple flag activated in onUnbind() that stops the loop inside the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually want a `Service`, but not an `IntentService`. You want a `Service` that will run in the background and which can be controlled through `Activity` (and will keep working after `Activity` is closed). This is a common architecture for such tasks. Here is an example of open source music player for Android:

https://github.com/kreed/vanilla/blob/master/src/org/kreed/vanilla/PlaybackService.java

Comment: Keep in mind services run on the main thread by default, but a thread in the service might do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. A bound service seems to be what I am looking for. My app structure is 1 Activity and 2 or 3 Fragments, so I don't need the service to continue to run when the Activity is closed. I actually want the opposite.